# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565. WIFI problem. Toshiba Satellite C55-A-1HN PSCG6E-09001CEN

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, toshiba-satellite

I have the following problem with my WIFI. My laptop works fine on **Windows 10**, but when I boot on **Ubuntu** I can’t use my WIFI adapter properly. It is clearly a problem with the driver or any possible setup of the driver. I would really appreciate your help giving me any insight on how to fix this issue. **Thank you.**

Also, if someone could share (a link with) all possible setups for my WIFI driver so that I could make some tests, I would appreciate it. **I hope to hear from the community soon, and thanks again.**

---

**THE PROBLEM**

When I am on Ubuntu 20.04, I have the following situations:

1. If I connect using USB tethering via cable, the internet is ok. And I can use Bluetooth normally with or without a speaker connected.
2. If I connect with WIFI and Bluetooth OFF, the internet is ok.
3. If I connect with WIFI and Bluetooth ON, the internet is okay.
4. If I connect with WIFI and Bluetooth ON, **AND** speaker connected (model Betron KB-S08 ON,) then I have a problem: the internet becomes very slow (unusable,) and it disconnects a lot. I can switch from any of those situations above as many times as I want and the same scenario is very responsive -always the same outcome.

However, when I am on **Windows 10**:

- My WIFI works fine with or without a speaker connected via Bluetooth.

**Detail:** I installed Ubuntu with a DUAL boot on my machine.

---

**CONFIGURATIONS**

- Laptop Toshiba SATELLITE C55-A-1HN PSCG6E-09001CEN
- Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01) ([link to Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsQualcomm))
- Internet Connection: Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016).
- Speaker Betron KB-S08

---

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0612]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)

⇒ Bluetooth turned OFF on Settings

sudo rfkill list

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

⇒ Bluetooth turned on Settings
 
sudo rfkill list

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: a6:db:31:fd:ce:9c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-56-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.51 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:c2400000-c247ffff memory:c2480000-c248ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8172 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 0c:50:a6:1d:ad:02
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:c1000000-c103ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: fe:ae:bc:70:21:9f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.128 link=yes multicast=yes
```

```
dmesg | grep ath9k

[   14.864739] ath9k 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

sudo iw dev

phy#0
    Interface wlp2s0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr a4:db:31:fd:ce:9c
        ssid 123
        type managed
        channel 11 (2462 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2462 MHz
        txpower 16.00 dBm
        multicast TXQ:
            qsz-byt qsz-pkt flows   drops   marks   overlmt hashcol tx-bytes    tx-packets
            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       0

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0612]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Toshiba Corporation QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1179:fa30]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3b1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
uname -r

5.4.0-56-generic

dmesg | grep -i blue

[   11.797990] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[   12.451990] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.452008] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.452011] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.452013] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.452016] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   32.098098] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   32.098101] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   32.098108] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   47.558125] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   47.558134] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   47.558143] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

iwconfig

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"123"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: E6:93:09:4A:8F:D6   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:6  Invalid misc:147   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3b1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
______________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1):

The above-mentioned method is working flawlessly.
rfkill event is not showing any soft resets.
both wifi and Bluetooth are working together.
Tried to upvote but do not have enough points.

#Though this is an old post. I have encountered this recently with the 18.04 version. However its with different laptop with the same wireless adapter

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242485)

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth and 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi share the same radio band.

You can enable BT coexistence technology for this Wi-Fi chip. Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf <<< "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1"
```

and reboot.

You can revert this setting by

```
sudo rm  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. After "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1" and reboot, the problem persists. Thank you Pilot6. Any other config I could try?

Comment: There is nothing else that can be done. Are you sure you did it correctly. You can check the file.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works with Windows 10 and not with Ubuntu? Doing my research I learned about this [Ndiswrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) module? Do you think it is a thing to try?

Comment: `ndiswrapper` is definitely not good. It is quite obsolete.

Comment: I've just learned that all drives are included in the kernel. Also, I learned that there is a kernel called ZEN which is famous for having all possible drives. I was wondering if this would be the right approach to fix this issue. What do you think, Pilot6? Thanks